# gradle: How to run JUnit tests of a child project from the root project?

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, junit

I have a root project called "myRootPrj" and several child projects (a EJB project, a UI project and so on). The EJB project "myEJBPrj" contains also JUnit testcases (under `myEJBPrj/src/test/java/...`).

In the build.gradle of the "myRootPrj" I have add:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  testCompile project(':myEJBPrj')
}
```

But when I call the "test" task of the "myRootPrj" I get:

```
 Skipping task ':test' as it has no source files and no previous output files.
```

Seems that the "myRootPrj" don't find any test classes ... right? Why that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things

First, about your question **How to run JUnit tests of a child project from the root project?**

Just run `gradle :myEJBPrj:test`

Then, setting `testCompile project(':myEJBPrj')` in `myRootPrj` project means that this one will use `myEJBPrj` sources to compile `myRootPrj` test sources but you don't have any test sources in your root project to the test task is ignored.

Comment: Thanks! `gradle :myEJBPrj:test` was the missing thing for me. For all which using Netbeans: In  Netbeans you must create a "Custom Task" (of the root project) with `:myEJBPrj:test` as task value.